# Fluidics, surface tension, metal screen

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

I often infuse tea in hot water. One infuser that I use is made of very fine mesh (stainless steel I believe). If I have the infuser empty and dry, and If I’m very careful in placing the infuser in the hot water, It will “float”. A similar question in this forum seems to address how this is possible, but this deals with an aluminum coin. See the post here - [Fluidics and surface tension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264280/fluidics-and-surface-tension/284970#284970).

My question is: Does a metal screen with fine enough holes act as a solid surface to the surface tension of the water?

Clearly mesh that is as coarse as chicken wire would not act as a solid surface, but it seems likely that there is a point where a screen becomes fine enough to no longer allow water, at least water at the calm surface, to penetrate the screen under a slight load.

I should indicate that the infuser has a small solid rim extending from the flat bottom and up the side, and a solid centre piece about the size of a dime. The rest of the infuser that contacts the water is all screen. I am relatively certain that this “floating” is not regular buoyancy since it cannot float to the surface after being forced even very slightly below the surface. The water easily passes through the screen however when the infuser is removed from the water. Also, it seems that the infuser will only behave this way when it is thoroughly dried; once it has be submerged, it does not seem to behave the same until dry.

As I said, the water easily passes through the screen, but I suppose that does not mean it is instantly dry; something to do with the attraction of water to metal being greater than the attraction of water to water I suppose. The apparent requirement to be dry is another indicator to me that the “floating” is related to surface tension.

Comment: In my judgment, you have correctly identified the mechanism.  To get a very rough estimate of how much pressure difference a mesh can support (using surface tension), assume an equivalent circular area, and use the equation $\Delta p=2\sigma /r$.

Comment: You specifically ask about water, but I wonder if you tried a medium such as olive oil, what the effect would be. I am not following any  particular idea here, I am just curious as to the ratio of the fluids cohesive force to its adhesive force.

Comment: I am also considering how this phenomenon might be used to some advantage. The primary difficulty in taking advantage of a floating screen are the requirements of the screen being dry, and the surface being calm. It would be most beneficial I think to consider the sinking rather than the floating as the useful feature; perhaps it could be used to determine if the water surface has been disturbed. So, it is probably useful as a sort of alarm or security device, and a scientific curiosity, or trick.

Do we see any more serious usefulness of this phenomenon than what I have proposed above?

Comment: Your point @TáMéCeart seems to bring up a somewhat contentious issue of the relationship between surface tension and viscosity. Some limited research suggests perhaps some disagreement exists in whether there is any relationship. From my understanding both are subject to the intensity of the cohesive force among the liquid’s molecules. See [link](http://www.mikeblaber.org/oldwine/chm1045/notes/Forces/Liquids/Forces03.htm). My logic sees more cohesion leading to more viscosity, less surface disturbances, and greater surface tension. I have seen articles that challenge this however.

Comment: I genuinely do see the phenomenon being useful as a teaching device, especially if it was designed around a boat shape, and introduced in basic physics courses, as a puzzle to be solved. In other words a scientific curiosity with a useful purpose. I am also aware that many (most?)  of the electronic devices in use today were also scientific curiosities until someone said the magic sound "hmmmm" or the magic phrase " I wonder  if...."